# Run powershell script with Python and capture output in Python while still showing it on powershell console

Tags: python, powershell

Hello I have the following bit of Python code that calls pwsh.exe with a powershell script. The powershell script only has 2 lines.

```
write-output "This is a line"
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
```

The Python code to call/run the script:

```
import subprocess

powershellProcess = r"X:\Program Files\PowerShell\6-preview\pwsh.exe"
fileToRun = r"D:\ProgrammingAndScripting\Powershell\Scripts\Test\test.ps1"

runit = subprocess.run([powershellProcess, fileToRun], check=True, capture_output=True)

print(str(runit.stdout) + "\n")
```

Now the code works. My question is as follows: When I use capture_output=True A powershell console will pop up remains empty and "This is a line" will appear in the Python IDE. When I remove capture_output=True A powershell console will pop up and shows "This is a line". The Python IDE will show: none.

Is there a way to both capture the output by python but also still show it in the powershell console window?